# Data structure python

Tags: python, database, pandas

I must save some data in python and I don't know how to save it.
The best think would be a data frame where elements are lists.

For example:

```
 id          nickname              other information
[32846846,["Mike", "Mikeal",...],[8,9,5,2,4],...]
[32846847,["Jack", "Jason",...],[5,3,2,4,6],....]
```

For each Id we can have different nicknames and different values.

How should I save my data?

Thanks

Comment: saving it to .txt or .csv if it is not several Gb of data? If it is several Gb of data, i suggest .fits format (pyfits module) but other formats are possible too (i got experience with .fits and know that it is very flexible to save whatever you want, but other formats exist as well)

Comment: Sorry I do not explain clearly the question. My problem is to construct a structure like the one in the example in python. A data frame where the elements can be lists

Comment: How large will it be? If it is not HUGE in amount of data, the IO to a .txt or .csv is negligible and easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer depends on how you plan to persist your data (database, flat file, etc...)

- if you use a flat file, a dict structure is easy to map to a CSV file
- if you use a SQL database : if it's an SQL database, you can either write your own mapping, or use an ORM.
- if it's a noSQL database, using json would probably be the best approach

In terms of python modelization, a dict (as suggested by badc0re) would work, but you may also create a dedicated python class, which would give you possibly more control and meaning on how you retrieve and set data (e.g. : person.nicknames vs dict[32846846][0])

Answer (score 0):

If you data is not huge, just dump it as JSON using the builtin [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json) module:

```
import json
data = [
    [32846846, ['Mike', 'Mikeal'], [8, 9, 5, 2, 4]],
    [32846847, ['Jack', 'Jason'], [5, 3, 2, 4, 6]]
]
with file('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

To read:

```
import json
with file('data.json') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
```